# IIS7 URL Rerwrite - how to replace all underscores with hyphens in a Regex?

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, iis-7

I am using the URL Rewrite feature in IIS7 to turn the URL:

```
/main.asp?category=Name_Of_A_Product
```

Into:

```
/category/name-of-a-product/
```

I have created the redirect & rewrite rules below which do the majority of the work, except I cannot find a way of replacing the underscores with hyphens.

Each URL can have between zero and many underscores and I'm trying to replace them in a single regular expression, to avoid chains of 301 redirects (as I believe that is bad for SEO).

Do you know how (or if) this is can be done?

```
<rule name="Redirect REAL to FRIEDNLY" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^main\.asp$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^category=([^=&amp;]+)($|&amp;(.*))$" />
     </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="category/{ToLower:{C:1}}/" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>

<rule name="Rewrite FRIEDNLY to REAL" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^category/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="main.asp?category={R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058789/iis7-url-rewriting-module-replace).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately IIS7 has a few limitations:

- you can only capture 9 groups `C:1` ... `C:9`
- there is only one string function and that's `ToLower`

Because of that you'll be limited to a URL with a maximum of 9 words separated by max 8 underscores (eg. `/main.asp?category=One_Two_Three_Four_Five_Six_Seven_Eight_Nine`) and you'll be forced to use 9 rewrite rules:

Single Word: **/main.asp?category=Product**

```
<rule name="Redirect REAL to FRIEDNLY 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^main\.asp$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^category=([A-Za-z]+)$" />
 </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="category/{ToLower:{C:1}}/" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Two Words: **/main.asp?category=Some_Product**

```
<rule name="Redirect REAL to FRIEDNLY 2" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^main\.asp$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^category=([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)$" />
 </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="category/{ToLower:{C:1}}-{ToLower:{C:2}}/" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Three Words: **/main.asp?category=Some_New_Product**

```
<rule name="Redirect REAL to FRIEDNLY 3" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^main\.asp$" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^category=([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)_([A-Za-z]+)$" />
 </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="category/{ToLower:{C:1}}-{ToLower:{C:2}}-{ToLower:{C:3}}/" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

### ...            ...            ...            ...            ...            ...