# IIS7 301 Redirect Regex to replace underscores with hyphen

Tags: regex, redirect, iis-7, http-status-code-301

I'm looking for some help using regex for my 301 redirects on IIS7.

I have links directing to pages like http://mydomain.co.uk/dir/colour_photo_copying.html and I'm hoping to rename these files to use hyphens instead of underscores.

On a one by one basis I can do this using the following:

```
<location path="colour-photo-copying.html">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="colour_photo_copying.html" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The only problem is I have few of these and was hoping to write a regex rule but am not sure how to do this.

I have come across this page: [IIS7 URL Rerwrite - how to replace all underscores with hyphens in a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617410/iis7-url-rerwrite-how-to-replace-all-underscores-with-hyphens-in-a-regex) but is not exactly what I'm hoping for.

Any regex guys out there to help?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found this solution and thought I'd share in case anyone else is lookig for it.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="replace underscore with hyphen" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)_(.*).*$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action url="/{R:1}-{R:2}" type="Redirect" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

If anyone feels they can improve please let me know.

Thanks,
Jas