# ASP.NET: Space in URL

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, request.querystring

I have a rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="rule 18X" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="^cheap-calls/(.+)/(.+)/$" ignoreCase="true" />
 <action type="Rewrite" url="CheapCalls.asp?calltype={R:1}&amp;country={R:2}"  />
</rule>
```

When I access `/cheap-calls/landline/Hong%20Kong/` and try to get a country value from url `Request.QueryString("country")` it gives me only `HongKong`. Why it removes the space?

Comment: My guess is it removes those characters due to potential script injection in querystrings. If it parsed everything that was in the querystring exactly, you could potentially input a malicious script into the querystring and have the server process it.

Comment: @dgarbacz, Thanks for response. Is there a posibillity to allow %20 in URL? I found only `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />` but this doesn't work for me.

Comment: This question shows how to replace %20 which is not what you want but maybe will lead you in the right direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058789/iis7-url-rewriting-module-replace