# IIS Rewriting and Passing String With Spaces to the Querystring

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to use rewrite rules in IIS to route requests like this:

`domain.com/users/some%20user%20name`

to

`domain.com/cms.asp?P=users/some user name`

The issue I am seeing is that the rule is removing the spaces altogether. Here is the rule I use:

```
            <rule name="Rewrite Everything Else to cms.asp" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="cms.asp?p={R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
            </rule>
```

What is causing the spaces to be removed during the rewrite and how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have spaces in a URL. The http spec states

> Spaces and control characters in URLs must be escaped for transmission
>   in HTTP, as must other disallowed characters.

[See here](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/url-spec.txt)

If you would prefer something more readable, perhaps rewrite the rules encoding the spaces as underscores or dashes. If you have a know amount of spaces you can probably catch it using something like

```
<rule name="Rewrite Everything Else to cms.asp" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)%20(.*)%20(.*)%20(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false"      />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}-{R:2}-{R:3}-{R:4}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
        </rule>
```

And then repeating the entry for :

```
^(.*)%20(.*)%20(.*)         replaced by:  {R:1}-{R:2}-{R:3}
^(.*)%20(.*)                replaced by:  {R:1}-{R:2}
```

Which will handle two and one space.

If you have an unknown number of spaces, you will probably need to implement an IIS rewrite module.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058789/iis7-url-rewriting-module-replace) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls) for more details